# Is "It's like watching Mitt and Mutt work" a reference to Mutt & Stuff?

Tags: slang

Hey English community,

I was watching [Best Fails Of The Year | Try Not To Laugh](https://youtu.be/d51diKTSi2M?feature=shared&t=279) and the sentence at the timestamp took me off guard, mostly because I've never heard it before and I really like it. I would like to use this turn of phrase but I feel like I should know what's it referring to, is it the show [Mutt & Stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_%26_Stuff)? It is the only reasonable Google result but it doesn't really appear to be relevant, mostly because the show doesn't feature a character "Mutt" nor "Mitt".

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's an established slang. It might be a reference to people they know.

Comment: The pair of names sounds reminiscent of a slapstick stage act of two clowns or bunglers.

Comment: I know, it reminded me of dumb and dumber or like the three stooges vibe but that doesn't quite have the ring to it

Comment: Maybe it's not even a reference to a specific thing but it's just supposed to evoke the general feeling of "slapstick stage act of two clowns or bunglers" as you put it

Comment: It doesn't seem a common phrase; it might be a confused version of the name of a genuine double act or two double acts. If someone can identify the original double act that would be an answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about details of a show rather than standard English usages.

Comment: Maybe it was intended to be a reference to the comic strip [Mutt and Jeff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_and_Jeff)?

Answer (score 0):

I have come here for the same reason, because I have just watched the same fails compilation and have never heard of Mitt & Mutt. Being from the Czech Republic, I instantly thought that it might be an English translation of the well know Czech animated double act [Pat & Mat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat_%26_Mat) / two clumsy handymen. It has aired all over the world so it might be that the person just misremembered the characters' names.